# Why don't my NA values work inside of ComplexHeatmap in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, heatmap

I realize that questions regarding mapping NA values have been asked for heatmaps in R, but I cannot figure out why these options do not work for my data.

I found this example of mapping NA values using ComplexHeatmap (https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-single-heatmap.html). I have run their example code using their NA matrix, and it works perfectly fine.

```
set.seed(123)
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 6; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
    rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
    rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
   )
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))
mat_with_na = mat
na_index = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(mat)*ncol(mat), replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 9))
mat_with_na[na_index] = NA
Heatmap(mat_with_na, name = "mat",col=rainbow(21), na_col = "black",
    column_title = "a matrix with NA values")
```

However, when I try the same procedure with my own data, I get the following error:
Error in hclust(get_dist(submat, distance), method = method) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)

My example data looks like this:
[image: Example matrix data]

I am able to make it work if I use the data.matrix function on my data and leave all generated columns. However, I am having an issue where the function generates an extra column of numbers in the "Description" column that are not real data. If I leave this column in with the NA values, the heatmap will work. However, if I remove this column, I get the above error.

This is the code I am using:

```
figure1 = read.xls("Figure1.xls") #load in data
rownames(figure1) <- figure1$Description #add row names
d1 = data.matrix(figure1,rownames.force=NA) #convert data to numerical matrix, for some reason this changes my description row into a column of random numbers (even though I force the rownames?)
d1[d1==0]=NA #change 0's to NA, these were originally blank in the data, but I changed them to 0s for importing
d2=d1[,-1] #remove the description column of extra values that gets made from the data.matrix function
Heatmap(d2, name = "mat", col=rainbow(21), na_col = "black",column_title = "a matrix with NA values")
```

I have been stuck on this for a long time, and I really need to figure out how to map these NA values to a background colour while also generating heatmaps (with a continuous colour scheme). I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me to figure out why I cannot get this procedure to work for my data. Maybe I am missing a difference between my data or my code and the example code?

Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your example data is (probably properly) locked, but this might speak to your issue [Pearson vs Euclidean distance method](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/155) from googling the error message.

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry about that. The data isn't actually my real data, I changed the numbers and row/column names so nothing is identifying. I posted a photo of what it looks like above for reference! Kind of a standard matrix with a lot of zeros (but the zeros were actually initially blank, I just filled them in to try to figure out the NA issue).  Looking at that link, do you think the problem might be too many NA values? This data was previously visualized by another individual, but they have since left the team and I have been asked to revisualize it with higher resolution (vector image).

Comment: Sorry, just an update, I also tried changing the distance method to pearson, spearman, kendall, and euclidean, with no success.

Comment: For any distance between measure you've got to have at least two points, so if you have a row  with one point, no distance, and that wrapped in hclust. The interesting thing in the link to the  ComplexHeatmap issues above is that someone in that thread wrote a function that calculates minimum number of points per row required per measure (or so it appeared), that you might deploy upon your data to find the offending rows, or so one hopes. You might also `dput(head(your_data))` if properly anonymized and append above.

Comment: Thank you so much, Chris! You nailed it. Turns out I had to turn off row clustering and only use column clustering to make it work. Some of the rows only had 1 value, whereas the columns had enough values to complete the clustering. The image looks exactly like they explained to me now. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. My only secret there, google the error code, because others have found them too.